# Is a good CRT monitor bad for your eyes?

Tags: display, external-display

I'd like to buy a new display for my office and I have two options - either buy a cheap 24" LCD or a huge used high-end CRT screen. Something like Sony FW900 or similar. CRTs have great colors, but I'd mostly use it for programming - I'm worried that the CRT would display the text with some fuzziness, but that might just be a bad experience from old low-end CRT. And I've heard that LCDs put less strain on one's eyes.

Would you recommend using high-end big CRT screen today, or is a modern LCD superior in every way? (weight and dimensions are not important)

Comment: I'd say unless you're doing some high-end graphics work (high enough to know what you'd want) then the LCD should be fine. I notice recently even a lot of the designers are going LCD now.

Comment: I'd note even with specialised applications, they're using LCDs. Also, a new lcd would come with a warranty, and connection options your old CRT wouldn't. Unless the CRT was *free* i wouldn't even consider the CRT

Comment: The GDM-FW900 is a really good monitor (we used to use a lot of them) but be aware that it has damper wires which you may find annoying once you spot them, it is also VERY deep and will steal a lot of your desk space.

Comment: There is no such thing as a good CRT.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend CRT - they have some issues related to the used technology (ghost image permanently burned on the screen on used CRTs, limited refresh rate, faded colors etc.). The LCDs are much better for the eyes, because the do not blink - the "rendering" of the image is quite different.

According to some internet discussions the CRTs have better contrast and colors, but I do not agree. After buying new LCD I always had to decrease brightness by about 30% and also a little bit decrease the contrast.

I switched to LCD some years ago and although I am using relatively cheap entry-level models by Asus, I never wanted my CRT back.

For programming you do not have to worry about color fidelity, quick refresh  etc. and in my opinion looking on lcd is much better - I have worse vision and use 24 inch TN lcd for things like numerical and spatial data analyses, GIS, sometimes also graphics and video editing and I am satisfied.